# How to fetch/detect empty fields with jsoup?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm parsing a website that includes movies. And a page has 20 items(movie-box). All these items must have same fields but unfortunately some do not have.

I mean, under div : movie-box ; there are, name, year, director. But some do not have year. So when I do;

```
movieBox.select(div["year"]);
```

fetching 19 items because one of movie-box does not even have year field.
So when I try to bind my recycleritem, Im facing IndexOutOfBounds error because some fields have 20 item, some 19.

What can I do with this issue ?

Here is some code about it ;

```
Elements movieSubject;

movieSubject= movieBox.select("div[class=movie-details existing-details]")
            .select("div[class=specials]")
            .select("div[class=movie-excerpt]")
            .select("p[class=story]"); // At this point some movie-box do not have story field.

RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getContext(), ..., movieSubject);

...

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

holder.textView_subject.setText(movieSubject.get(position).text());

}
```

Comment: I would check each field and assign it some default value if it's empty (it can be something like an empty string, so it will not be actually displayed).

Comment: @TDG well, I've considered it but problem is when u do document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get(); this fetch all data once and when u do Elements movieBox= document.select("div[class=movie-box]"); u can not seperate fields so u can not put for/if loops in between. And its fetching 19 data unfortunately. So not even taking that empty field. Thats why we can not determine it. Actually this is the main question already, how should I check ? You can try to give me code sample :)

Comment: To answer your question I need to know the url and see the way you fetch it.

Comment: @TDG I put the code already. And I dont know if I can give url here (might be forbidden, Im newbie so ...) But I should say that is the site : unutulmazfilmler.pw

Comment: Sorry, still cannot understand the problem. Can you give a propoer example of the expected output and the actual output?